# How to add setter to Class using Lombok @Value

Tags: setter, lombok

```
@Value
@Builder
public class XXX {
    String field1;
    String field2;
    String field3;
}
```

I have a class using lombok `@Value` as above, where each field will be made private and final. Now, I'd like to have a setter for `field3`, which does not work because `field3` is final. What should I do here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `@Value` then. `@Value` is for value classes, i.e., classes whose instances are immutable. If you want a field to be mutable, then you clearly don't have a value class.

Instead, make all other fields `final` manually. Then use `@Getter` and `@RequiredArgsConstructor` (and `@EqualsAndHashCode` if required) on the class, and `@Setter` on all non-final fields. (Or use `@Data`, but carefully read its documentation.)

Comment: I tried this, but it seems Getter+Setter+AllArgsConstructor is not sufficient. It keeps bugging. Documentation said: "In practice, Value is shorthand for: final ToString EqualsAndHashCode AllArgsConstructor FieldDefaults(makeFinal = true, level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE) Getter". So maybe I should add all these annotations?

Comment: Solved by adding  EqualsAndHashCode

Answer (score 1):

I used @NonFinal and @Setter to achieve this without adjusting too much and staying in the lombok workflow.

I had a large model that I didn't want to refactor to have final variables on everything, so this was the simplest and cleanest solution for me.

```
@Value
@Builder
public class XXX {
    String field1;
    String field2;

    @NonFinal
    @Setter
    String field3;
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, helped me to achieve exactly what I wanted. Just as remark: `@NonFinal` is still an experimental feature at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

### Why is the field3 final? When a variable is declared with final keyword, its value can’t be modified, essentially, a constant. You should remove it!

Here you set the properties when you create the object

XXX s= XXX.builder().field1("XX").field2("XX").field3("XX").build();
setter are not needed here

Comment: Because all fields will be made as final by @Value; so what changes to make for annotations so that we could specifically make field3 NOT final and have a setter for it?